# Set an image source from code behind

Tags: silverlight

I have a textbox where user will enter the url of the image :

suppose the user enters the following string -> C:\Users\malcolm\Desktop\img.png

**imgSilverPart** is a image control AND **imageUrl** is a string what i am getting from a textbox.

**imgSilverPart.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));**

But the image is not being displayed.

Comment: Silverlight cannot access files straight from your hard drive like you are trying to do. That would be a huge security risk. Silverlight can only access files in its own storage space, called IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work. Silverlight runs in a safe Sandbox and you can't just access a file on the desktop.
So you have to call an OpenFileDialog, get the Stream to the file the user selected and set the Stream as source of the BitmapImage.

Add a Button in XAML and do the following in the Click event handler:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (openFileDlg.ShowDialog().Value)
      {
         using (var stream = openFileDlg.File.OpenRead())
         {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            imgSilverPart.Source = bitmapImage;
         }
      }
   }
```

As an alternative it's possible to use some special folders if your application runs in elevated trust mode as Out-Of-Browser app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the kind of Uri was not determined corectly. Try tu use UriKind.Relative or UriKind.Absolute with valid relative or absolute url string.

Comment: Oh. Now I realized that the file is on your local machine and is not served via HTTP. In that case Rene's answer should guide you in a right direction.